# How can I get reputation points temporarily

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

People learn about the mistakes once they make it. I am long time user and occasional user of SO. I am currently at a situation where having 2k reputation for bounties would help me tremendously. I never thought that this feature could be so useful. Otherwise I would have worked on gaining more points. But this is a lesson I learnt.

I don't want free reps and I am willing to pay for it either through time or money. But I understand that both options are not available in SO. How can I get help on adding gaining reputation at least temporarily.

I'm not trying to ask for free reputations. I'm just asking if there is a way to get reputation temporarily from someone to place in bounties. You might know that there is no way of doing this, but I don't.

Hope the downvotes stop.

Comment: No one can give you rep, even if they wanted to, one thing you can do is go to SO chat and explain you cannot get answer and would someone consider doing it for you bui make sure the question is up to standers.

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: thanks @MarkKirby But I don't understand the other vote downs

Comment: Your question is badly worded, you seem to be just asking for free rep, that never goes well here and comes up a lot. I would guess that is why the downvotes but I have no way to know for sure.

Comment: My curiosity is eating at me. Why would you temporarily need rep? What purpose would that serve?

Comment: To use for bounties

Comment: My curiosity is eating me too. What kind of posts that make you needing 2k to use for bounty? Are they really worth the bounty?

Comment: It's not a single bounty. It's is going to be a series of bounties. I'm trying to analyze an industry standard on how data warehousing is done in different companies. I myself have worked on many DWH projects. But I wish to know how it is being done in other companies and some nitty gritties. Here are some examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805578/how-surrogate-keys-are-handles-in-hive/51805742?noredirect=1#comment90586136_51805742  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455138/definition-of-daily-active-users-dau These require participation from authoritative sources

Comment: I think trying to get feedback on such a broad base isn't really what SE is for.  We're all about specific, *focused* questions and answers.  You might get some bits and pieces from questions you ask, but trying to analyze something across the breadth of several companies isn't really feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this, in theory:

- You could get the other person to upvote your posts.
- You could get the other person to accept your answers.
- You could get the other person to approve your suggested edits.
- You could get the other person [to transfer rep to you via bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169835/274942).

All of these will work. And all of these will rapidly get you both suspended, as they would constitute targeted voting, or an equivalent thereof.

On Stack Exchange, we vote for the post, not the person. Upvotes primarily indicate that content is good; if someone targets another person and upvotes the posts, they're *probably* not merely upvoting good content - they're ignoring post quality entirely. And that's not good.

Now, you could very very very nicely ask someone in chat if they'll place a bounty on one of their questions. There are some charitable people on SE; I try to be one of them from time to time. But I wouldn't advise soliciting from other users that you don't already know. So . . . this probably isn't a good path, either.

Comment: Than you for helping with an answer. I really appreciate it